# cant get a pointer to wxwidget object, using wxsmith

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

straight to the point:
Im learning wxsmith and wxwidgets toolkit, i created some basic GUI containing one button and 2 static text fields. GUI is compilling ok so far. My frame name is proba2Frame, then im adding my own function which is not a member of any class but i declared in header file for proba2Frame that my function is a friend. Below is code of my function:

```
   wxStaticText * dawajpointera()
    {
    wxStaticText * text;
    text = proba2Frame.wxStaticText.StaticText1;
    return text;
    }
```

im getting error:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

What exactly im doing wrong and how to get a pointer StaticText in case my solution is completely wrong ?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Not enough context in the question but to access `static` class members use `::`.

Comment: TU POLACY. Przejmujemy ten wątek. WPISUJCIE MIASTA!!!1

Comment: @hjmd "static text" referred to the wxStaticText widget, not C++'s `static` construct.

Answer (score 2):

You make it sound like `proba2Frame` is the name of a class inheriting wxFrame?

If so, you're haveing problems because you haven't created an instance of `proba2Frame`, and you're trying to access a part of it that hasn't been constructed. Your main frame class is simply a template for your GUI, not the GUI itself.

The best way to go about it would probably be to take an instance of `proba2Frame` as a parameter-

```
wxStaticText* dawajpointera(proba2Frame *frame)
{
    return frame->StaticText1;
}
```

Of course, that function itself was a bit pointless, but I'll assume that you're going to do something more involved with the pointer afterwards, and want it set to a pointer named `text` within the function for the sake of brevity.

```
void func(proba2Frame *frame)
{
    wxStaticText *text = frame->StaticText1;
    // Do something with text
}
```

If you're doing this, though, please consider making the function a method of `proba2Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

wxStaticText is the name of a wxWidgets class.  You should not be naming attributes of your frame 'wxStaticText'.  Despite the code you have posted, I doubt that you have really done such a terrible thing.  What you probably meant to write, I would guess, is:

```
text =  proba2Frame.StaticText1;
```

I am guessing that the name of the attribute is StaticText1, a pointer to an instance of the wxStaticText class.

Comment: I tried that also, same error. But you are right, StaticText1 is a pointer of wxStaticText type and is a member of proba2Frame class, as stated in header file.